# Supervisor eventlistener in subshell

Tags: python, bash, supervisord

I am writing a supervisor event listener that can send process state events into a queue for further processing. The event listener is written in Python, let's call it handler.py. I have an internal build and release system for Python which allows me to create virtual environments before executing Python scripts from any of my servers using an omnipresent bash script (called launcher.sh) that essentially looks like this

```
...
create virtualenv
activate virtualenv
python -m main_module
```

I then configure the event listener in my supervisor instance like so:

```
[eventlistener:feedback]
command = launcher.sh handler.py
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

I can see the handler printing READY\n to it's stdout but none of the events propagate to it and eventually supervisor starts to complain about the event buffer having overflowed. If I then change the event listener configuration to call python directly, like so, things come to life.

```
[eventlistener:feedback]
command = <path to virtualenv>/bin/python handler.py
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

The one thing I tried is to call python using exec inside launcher.sh and I can see no subprocess is spawned that way but it still doesn't work. I am wondering if this is related to buffering of stdout writes or something of the sort but my knowledge at this depth is limited. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, by reading the supervisor code it turns out it checks for stdout_text.startswith('READY') so I just had to make sure my launcher.sh script did not print anything out before launching the event handler.